# Animate Indexed Stack in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

How to animate the transition between IndexedStack children ? I have implemented it with bottom BottonNavigationBar. Here is the code:

````
            index: navigationIndex.state,
            children: [
              AnimatedSwitcher(
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                  transitionBuilder: (widget, animation) => SizeTransition(
                      sizeFactor: animation,
                      child: Scaffold(body: Center(child: Logo())))),
              Scaffold(body: Center(child: Logo())),
              Scaffold(body: Center(child: Logo())),
              Scaffold(body: Center(child: Logo()))
            ],
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            currentIndex: navigationIndex.state,
            onTap: (index) {
              navigationIndex.state = index;
            },
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Text(""), label: "Home", tooltip: "news and feed"),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Text(""),
                  label: "Questions",
                  tooltip: "news and feed"),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Text(""), label: "Quizz", tooltip: "news and feed"),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Text(""), label: "Grow", tooltip: "news and feed"),
            ],
          ),```
````

Answer (score 0):

try this, [animations](https://pub.dev/packages/animations), Fade through:

```
  int pageIndex = 0;

  List<Widget> pageList = <Widget>[
    _FirstPage(),
    _SecondPage(),
    _ThirdPage(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Fade through')),
      body: PageTransitionSwitcher(
        transitionBuilder: (
          Widget child,
          Animation<double> animation,
          Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
        ) {
          return FadeThroughTransition(
            animation: animation,
            secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
            child: child,
          );
        },
        child: pageList[pageIndex],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: pageIndex,
        onTap: (int newValue) {
          setState(() {
            pageIndex = newValue;
          });
        },
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.photo_library),
            label: 'Albums',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.photo),
            label: 'Photos',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            label: 'Search',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```